# Customize UIPickerView

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I want to implement multiple `pickerView` (combobox) on my form, but the `pickerView` implemented on xcode is too bigger, and that's the only one we can use, so I want to know if we can customize the `UIPickerView` like a field when we tap a picker view appear. I want something light, because here the `UIPickerView` take a lot of place on my view.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you don't want the picker view to be visible at all times. You can achieve this by assign a picker view to any responder's `inputView`. If that responder then becomes the first responder, the picker view will be shown in lieu of the keyboard.

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr Ye sor a dropdown list view like in android, I'll look on your proposition

Answer (score 0):

[How to change UIPickerView height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573979/how-to-change-uipickerview-height)

please check this in iOS9 picker view rect is changeable.

form iOS 9 release notes.

UIPickerView and UIDatePicker are now resizable and adaptive—previously, these views would enforce a default size even if you attempted to resize them. These views also now default to a width of 320 points on all devices, instead of to the device width on iPhone

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-9.0/

Comment: Yes but the height is not the real problem, if I set a little height, change the item will be difficult by not seeing the other items. I want to have an another style of picker view like a drown down list like in android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900315/ios-drop-down-view

Ben have a look at this answer there are some open source libraries which implement your need.

If you really wants a perfect dropdown list then i think you have to implement yourself.

Comment: I prefer to don't use library, I'm gonna see something by using uitextfield and appear a uipickerview on tap you think it's possible ?

Comment: yep why not. Tapping on text field , create a picker view and add it just below the textfield, on selecting a row in picker view hide it. Or depends upon your need. :)