# Drop-down style UIPickerView?

Tags: ios, swift, drop-down-menu, uipickerview

I was wondering how to get a `UIPickerView` to slide up from the bottom of the screen after tapping on a drop-down style button. Like in the image below:

[image: CloudConvert screenshot of a drop-down style UIPickerView]

I've run into this type of picker views a lot in the apps that I use regularly, so honestly I was expecting to easily find this picker view by setting the `UIPickerView`'s `style` property, or something like that. Is this even a `UIPickerView` or do I have to create this kind of view manually?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way of doing this is to have a normal `UITextField` and then assign a `UIPickerView` as the `inputView` of that textfield. That way, instead of a keyboard appearing when you tap your textfield, you get your pickerview.

#### Example

First declare a normal `UIPickerView` instance:

```
let yourPicker = UIPickerView()
```

and an outlet to a `UITextField`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var yourTextField: UITextField!
```

In your `viewDidLoad` you tie the elements together

```
yourPicker.delegate = self
yourPicker.dataSource = self
yourTextField.inputView = yourPicker
```

And then you need to implement the required methods of `UIPickerViewDelegate` and `UIPickerViewDataSource`

Finally. In `pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)` you update the value of your textfield:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
   yourTextField.text = yourDataArrayUsedInThePicker[row]
}
```

#### Read more

Description of `inputView`
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html

A way better explaination than mine:
[Show UIPickerView text field is selected, then hide after selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26819423/show-uipickerview-text-field-is-selected-then-hide-after-selected)

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! Just to be clear, if I set my picker view as the `inputView` of my text field, does the appearance of my text field automatically change to something like the screenshot from my original post, or do I still have to modify the text field manually to make it look like that? Bascially, the most important thing to me is the little arrow on the right side of the text field, indicating that a picker view will appear if the text field is tapped on.

Comment: Unfortunately you'd still have to modify the textfield to make it look like a "drop down". You could add a button with an action that would set focus on the textfield, something like `yourTextField.becomeFirstResponder()` should do it.

Comment: But...I dunno, if you are looking for something looking like a dropdown then maybe it would be worth checking if someone has made a component for that, which you can use (I found this for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900315/ios-drop-down-view).

Comment: Yeah I think that iOS drop down view will do the trick. I'll check it out. Thanks!